# How can I optimize GET request?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I face an issue related to optimization of REST service.
Time it takes to work with particular amount of requests is above ten times greater than what I may be expected to provide.

public class Request {

```
String url;
CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
HttpGet request;
HttpResponse result;
String json;

public Request(String URL)
{
    url = URL;
    httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    request = new HttpGet(url);
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    try {
    result = httpClient.execute(request);
    json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
    }
}
```

Can you please let me know if there are any modifications I can supply or what are libraries I could consider as for faster handling of requests?

Comment: Buy faster internet. Implement a cache. Honestly though, if you are making REST calls, you should use a REST framework and let it handle the complexity for you.

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating the `httpClient` outside of the function.

So the `httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` will happen only once.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with one httpClient for all requests amount of time was at least if I'm not mistaken 2x lower than before. There may still be room for me to shorten (around 4,5x) though.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a comment, but I'm not allowed to add a comment yet. Unless your application runs on top of very scarce resources, you should use a rest framework to do the heavy lifting for you. It's designed to be as efficient and optimized as possible.

A good and lightweight one is [OkHttp](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately OkHttp didn't resolve the case.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is related with the size of the response, you can also try to speed it up compressing it with GZIP, using some binary response like Protobuffers, or both at same time. It will make the whole thing faster... But you need to try and compare.

With Protobuffers you will make both the serialization and the transmission faster, for sure. But it takes time to understand how Protobuffer works, and also implement it on both server and client. And if it's your first time, you will probably introduce some new bugs. We're humans after all.

About GZIP, it's simpler, but if the response is too short, gzip can make it bigger instead of smaller. So, you will need to also invest some time on it.